# Convert rsa keys into pem format

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, rsa, pem

I have an RSA keypair in decimal format like this:

```
N:  131380300130444423689465024460852313971098730922811994958210650530501686748132880102503190365296216968351535889369502651601697016994057094307459860310817213533755054007252477133258682280599098830508996183566745393684789271087614478241425320061726198137426426490142200235611844869472546908487777450913733956847
E:  65537
D:  80297204963989065579466889768824319637950465647088430322583084471355799970954766200860052948440422519604509972209521777162610037317804551817832746460011635684494412969232268215156141089492528372187753214602862715747188949826914338588271329247689858629892142371556575928454002581316958535707202236560574870513
P:  1224584489781086541356110467036625215751324632060784958572680296867401248241071907258999049522896850209985495153134079568147009917335592949603533318035603
Q:  10728561502026755927334064184961854822182870744919733441933716834397978727498603128211162084788541605856166966893670172798846339557261092973389679407794073
```

While OpenSSL (for PHP) requires that the key should be in PEM format. How do i convert them? It is very important that the public & private key "stays the same" (By that i mean that i can't just make a new keypair).

**EDIT:**
Or is it easier to make a pem cartificate and extracting all of those values in **decimal** format? And if so, how?

Comment: You do realize that you just published both the public and private keys. This means the key pair you published in your question can and ***SHOULD*** be discarded right away!.. Hopefully those numbers in your question were just examples..

Comment: Good. Then, have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865819/rsa-hex-keys-to-pem-format

Comment: Yes, but is there a **concrete** answer to that question? The source code is in C.

Comment: Whay **really** matters is that i can have the same keypair in pem format **and** in decimal format.

Answer (score 2):

Short of doing it yourself (writing a small utitlity program to convert the key to PEM format) you could use the Java tool at this URL: http://www.platanus.cz/blog/converting-rsa-xml-key-to-pem

It requires the input to be in an XML file but that should be trivial for you to generate.

Comment: Hhhmmmmmm, Java? Is there another option? (I mean language) (Like C# or..?)

Comment: There's a link to the source code of that little tool on the page. http://www.platanus.cz/uploads/production/document/3/XMLSec2PEM.java.txt Simply convert that to C# if you need to. Java translates to C# really easily for such a small program.

Answer (score 0):

Try ssh2openpgp in the [monkeyspehere](http://web.monkeysphere.info/) project.

UPDATE: Try also [this](http://sysmic.org/dotclear/index.php?post/2010/03/24/Convert-keys-betweens-GnuPG,-OpenSsh-and-OpenSSL). It explains how to go from, in two steps, OpenSSH → OpenSSL → GnuPG.